# How to use methods of a class without a constructor, in another class in C#

Tags: c#, mono, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I'm using the Libbcm2835.Net library @ https://github.com/frankhommers/LibBcm2835.Net , on Mono. I'll need to call methods of the Bcm2835 class which is given in the library as:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LibBcm2835.Net
{
  public sealed partial class Bcm2835
  {
//please note: I added the constructor below and tried to use it to 
//instantiate the object to be used in ADS1256.cs, but to no avail. I tried: 
// Bcm2835 bcm2835 = new Bcm2835(1); And then invoking methods from bcm2835. 
//But that gives me "An object reference is needed to access the non-static 
//member ADS1256.bcm2835"
    public Bcm2835(int a ) { }  
    ....all the methods here-on being non-static...
  }
}
`
```

I now want to use this in another class ADS1256.cs as below:

```
using System;
using LibBcm2835.Net;
namespace ForceSeer2
{
    public class ADS1256
    {       

        public ADS1256()
        {
        }


         static Bcm2835 instance;
        public static Bcm2835 Instance {
            get { return instance;}
        }
      //example of a method in this class that uses a method from the class 
      //Bcm2835:
        public static int initializeSPI ()
            {
              //if i had done Bcm2835 bcm2835 = new Bcm2835(1); at the top, 
             //i would now do : if (bcm2835.bcm2835_init ()==0) instead of 
              //the upcoming line, leading then to the error: "An object 
             //reference is needed to access the non-static 
             //member ADS1256.bcm2835"
                if (Instance.bcm2835_init ()==0)
                    return -1;
                else {
                    Instance.bcm2835_spi_begin ();
                    Instance.bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder ((byte)Bcm2835.bcm2835SPIBitOrder.BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_LSBFIRST);
                    Instance.bcm2835_spi_setDataMode ((byte)Bcm2835.bcm2835SPIMode.BCM2835_SPI_MODE1);  //whats this about??
                    Instance.bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider ((ushort)Bcm2835.bcm2835SPIClockDivider.BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_256);//whats this about??
                    Instance.bcm2835_gpio_fsel ((byte)SPICS, (byte)Bcm2835.bcm2835FunctionSelect.BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);//whats this about??
                    Instance.bcm2835_gpio_set ((byte)SPICS);//sets SPICS to HIGH
                    Instance.bcm2835_gpio_fsel ((byte)DRDY, (byte)Bcm2835.bcm2835FunctionSelect.BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);//whats this about??
                    Instance.bcm2835_gpio_set_pud ((byte)DRDY, (byte)Bcm2835.bcm2835PUDControl.BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP); //whats this about??


                    return 1;
                }
            }
```

This kind of use gives me the NullReferencePointer exception at the line:

```
if (Instance.bcm2835_init ()==0)
```

What causes this? How may I correct it?

Comment: You are expecting to use and object without event initializing it. Why? what stops you from using constructor of the class to create an object of it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya In fact there was no constructor there. I inserted it and tried to call it. It however gives the same exception

Comment: _"In fact there was no constructor there"_ -- what are you talking about? The code you posted shows a constructor. You just have to pass an `int` value to it. Frankly, your question makes no sense...to call non-static methods, you have to create an instance. So, **create an instance**. If that doesn't work, you need to explain better why not.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You mean this line:  Bcm2835 bcm2835 = new Bcm2835(1); And then invoking methods from bcm2835. But that gives me "An object reference is needed to access the non-static member ADS1256.bcm2835"

Comment: The code you posted does not show any such member `bcm2835` of the class `ADS2156`, so the error message you describe makes no sense. If you want help, you need to post a better question, with a good [mcve] showing clearly everything relevant to the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho just added comments in ADS1256.cs to clarify the alternative use you mentioned.

Comment: If you want to use a field in `static` code, the field itself also needs to be `static`. Which you'd know if you'd done a search on Stack Overflow for the error message you got.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ah. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following code before calling bcm2835_Init method:

```
// Blinks on RPi Plug P1 pin 7 (which is GPIO 4)
const Byte pin = (byte)Bcm2835.RPiGPIOPin.RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_07;

// Will extract (from embedded resource) and compile the library 
// if it doesn't exist in the same directory as LibBcm2835.dll.
Bcm2835.ExtractAndCompileLibraryIfNotExists();

// Grabbing the instance will dynamically load the libbcm2835.so 
// library, so make sure it's there before accessing this property.
Bcm2835 bcm2835 = Bcm2835.Instance;
```

Comment: I do see that in the sample blink code. But that only compiles in the main(). My ADS1256.cs is a service class.

Comment: What error do you see when trying to compile it? It seems to me this code is the only way

Comment: I just updated the question to include the error in comments right above the constructor i've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could use Singleton design pattern:

```
using System;
using LibBcm2835.Net;
namespace ForceSeer2
{
    public class ADS1256
    {       
        public ADS1256()
        {
        }

        private static Bcm2835 instance;
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();

        public static Bcm2835 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if(instance == null)
                {
                    lock(syncRoot)
                    {
                        if(instance == null)
                            instance = new Bcm2835();
                    }
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }

        //example of a method in this class that uses a method from the class 
        //Bcm2835:
        public static int initializeSPI ()
        {
             //Your method implementation here
        }

        //Other class members here
    }
}
```

Comment: They may or may not need a singleton pattern, but your code above won't compile. Not very useful.